# How to cancel one of many threads in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, multithreading, swift

I have a function that starts 3 asynchronous threads. Each thread do something which take some time. When some thread finish first, I need it to stop the other 2, but I don't know how to do it (yet).

My code:

```
    class SomeController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    threads();
}

func threads(){
    
    let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue();

    operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock(
        {
            let thread = NSThread.currentThread();
            let threadNumber = thread.valueForKeyPath("private.seqNum").integerValue;
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(30);
            
            println("Task #1 completed on thread #\(threadNumber)");
            
    })
    
    operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock(
        {
            let thread = NSThread.currentThread();
            let threadNumber = thread.valueForKeyPath("private.seqNum").integerValue;
            
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(20);
            println("Task #2 completed on thread #\(threadNumber)");
            
    })
    
    operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock(
        {
            let thread = NSThread.currentThread();
            let threadNumber = thread.valueForKeyPath("private.seqNum").integerValue;
            
            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(5);
            println("Task #3 completed on thread #\(threadNumber)");
    })
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really a question about canceling an `NSThread`.  Rather, it's a question of how to cancel an `NSOperation`.  In this case, it's relatively easy to cancel all the operations since you're creating a single `NSOperationQueue` for the sole purpose of executing your three blocks.  Just send the operationQueue a cancelAllOperations message:

```
operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
```

The unfortunate part is that operation canceling is really cooperative, so within the operation you have to periodically check `isCancelled` and terminate as required:

```
var operation3:NSOperation?
operation3 = operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock {
    let thread = NSThread.currentThread()
    let threadNumber = thread.valueForKeyPath("private.seqNum").integerValue
    var timeout = 5

    while timeout-- > 0 && !operation3.isCancelled {
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1)
    }

    println("Task #3 completed on thread #\(threadNumber)")

    operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
}
```

Comment: addOperationWithBlock is a void method.

Comment: Good point, OP will need to subclass `NSOperation` instead of using `addOperationWithBlock`, but the jist of the answer remains the same :)

Comment: I men't how to cancel a single operation not all of them :)

Comment: That's where gnasher729's comment comes into play.  `addOperationWithBlock` doesn't return the `NSOperation`, so you can't cancel them individually.  To cancel the operation you'll need to sub-class `NSOperation` and roll your own.  Then you can send use `operation.cancel()` to cancel an individual operation.

Answer (score 1):

If you create an operation with addOperationWithBlock, you can cancel it all you like, it has no effect. If you want to *cancel* an operation, I recommend not using a block, but subclassing NSOperation. The task that is getting executed must check manually when it's cancelled and finish the task; you can't do that with addOperationWithBlock.