# how to cancel a thread in swift?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

Is there any ways to cancel a thread in swift using GDC?
I mean main thread will continuous adding task to the queue, and then will decide to will a specific task.
Does dispatch_release will cancel all the tasks that are not running in the queue?

Comment: You can use a NSOperationQueue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850867/how-to-cancel-one-of-many-threads-in-swift?rq=1